# Set the initial position of a Dialog Modal Page in Oracle Apex

Tags: plsql, modal-dialog, oracle-apex

I am currently working on Oracle Apex v21.1

In my application, the users can insert items with a [form on a Dialog Modal Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R62qB.png).

Based on the users choice, they can insert multiple insert at once, dynamically creating more fields. However, this leads the form to being bigger. Considering the form is bigger, its height is increasing on top and on bottom, which leads to the fields moving on the screen, because the form is always centered on the page, here's an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12sEH.png)

What I would like to do, is something like setting the initial position of the form on the top of the page (maybe with something like an x/y axis ?)

The form would be like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZKii.png), and increasing his size would only let him expand by the bottom, not the top, just [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSo4g.png)

I hope this is clear enough for you guys, do not hesitate to ask me questions for more details,

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the below steps to achieve this:

1. Put the below CSS code in the Page -> CSS -> Inline section of the parent page.
   **What is the parent page:** The page from which you are opening the modal page.

```
.ui-dialog.modal-dialog--pullout{
   top: 0!important;
}
```

[image]

2. Put the class name **modal-dialog--pullout** in the Page -> Dialog -> CSS Classes of the Modal Dialog Page.

[image]